# Multiple ellipses in D3 not visible with no error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, graphics

A simple program for multiple ellipse I have written. The program shows no error but also no ellipse is being seen. Though i tried add multiple random colors for it. I think there is some slight mistake somewhere. Can someone help out?

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    //our basic data 
     var customData = [
        { "x": 30, "y": 30, "width": 20, "height" : 10 },
        { "x": 70, "y": 70, "width": 20, "height" : 20},
        { "x": 110, "y": 100, "width": 20, "height" : 30}
     ];

    //Make an SVG Container
    var mySVG = d3.select("svg");

    //create ellipses skeleton by data  
    var ellipses = mySVG.selectAll("ellipse")
            .data(customData)
            .enter()
            .append("ellipse");

    //Draw the Rectangle
    ellipses.append("ellipse")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("rx", function (d) { return d.width; })
        .attr("ry", function(d) { return d.height; })
        .attr("fill",function() { return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"; });

});

</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="500px" height="500px"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending ellipse elements twice. Here is the working snippet.

```js
var customData = [{
  "x": 30,
  "y": 30,
  "width": 20,
  "height": 10
}, {
  "x": 70,
  "y": 70,
  "width": 20,
  "height": 20
}, {
  "x": 110,
  "y": 100,
  "width": 20,
  "height": 30
}];

//Make an SVG Container
var mySVG = d3.select("svg");

//create ellipses skeleton by data  
var ellipses = mySVG.selectAll("ellipse")
  .data(customData)
  .enter()
  .append("ellipse");

// Removed second append from here

//Draw the Rectangle
ellipses.attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("rx", function(d) {
    return d.width;
  })
  .attr("ry", function(d) {
    return d.height;
  })
  .attr("fill", function() {
    return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500px" height="500px"></svg>
```